# How to create Pocketbook logo?

Tags: file-format, ebook-management

I have two images in logo folder preinstalled in ebook (Pocketbook 612).

Well, I take them and see this information.

```
> identify 1_st.bmp
> 1_st.612.bmp BMP 600x800 600x800+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 481KB 0.000u 0:00.010
```

Next, I try to create same formatted images with `convert` utility of `imagemagick` and with `gimp`.

**Convert utility**

I use this command to create images:

```
 convert Ah.jpg -resize \!600x800 -colorspace Gray -depth 8 -type palette Ah.bmp
```

And `identify` check:

```
> identify Ah.bmp 
> Ah.bmp BMP 600x800 600x800+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 508KB 0.020u 0:00.030
```

But book says: unsupported format

**GIMP**

I try to create pictures by gimp, cut them to size 600x800 and use grayscale mode.

And `identify` check:

> identify Oh.bmp
>   Oh.bmp BMP 600x800 600x800+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 1.44MB 0.000u 0:00.010

Again, book says: unsupported format

Also, I rename pictures with suffix `.612` `(Oh.612.bmp)` but this method doesn't work too.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met with same problem on my Pocketbook 912, and after some time I figured out how to solve it. BMP should be in indexed color mode and without compression. ImageMagick by default producing RLE compressed bmp.
For indexed palette I am using default logo image `1_st.912.bmp`.

So if you have image with right resolution you can do this:

```
$ convert someimage.png \
    -background white \
    -alpha remove \
    -depth 8 \
    -colors 256 \
    -type grayscale \
    -remap 1_st.912.bmp \
    -dither FloydSteinberg \
    -compress none  BMP3:outlogo.912.bmp
```

Here's another example, how I converted [OpenBSD's puffy](http://www.openbsd.org/art/puffy/puf800X689.gif) to pocketbook logo.

```
$ wget -O Puffy.gif http://www.openbsd.org/art/puffy/puf800X689.gif # download image
$ convert Puffy.gif \
    -background white -gravity center -extent 825x1200  \
    -alpha remove -depth 8 -colors 256 -type grayscale \
    -remap 1_st.912.bmp -dither FloydSteinberg -compress none \
    BMP3:puffy.912.bmp
```

This command will resize canvas, center original image and convert it to supported by pocketbook bmp file. *Note*: since you have other resolution, you should change `825x1200` string to your device's resolution.